# Removing specific characters from a string

Tags: php

i have a cookie which looks like this:

```
4+5+6+2+2+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+5+5+5+5+6+6+6+6+7+7+7+7+8+8+8+8+14+14+14+14+14+21+21+21+21+21
```

i need to remove specific characters based on user input.

so, for example, if i wanted to remove the number 2, it would look like this:

```
4+5+6+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+5+5+5+5+6+6+6+6+7+7+7+7+8+8+8+8+14+14+14+14+14+21+21+21+21+21
```

how can it be done in PHP?

thanks

Comment: It's a very simple thing to do, but Google has everything you need to know with the simplest of searches. http://bit.ly/1uJGmHd - have a look at `str_replace()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$input="4+5+6+2+2+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+5+5+5+5+6+6+6+6+7+7+7+7+8+8+8+8+14+14+14+14+14+21+21+21+21+21";

$arr = explode('+',$input);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
    if($val==2) unset($arr[$key]);
}

$out = implode('+', $arr);

echo $out;
```

Comment: I feel like there could be a regexp solution, but this is the easier-to-understand anwser :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $str = "4+5+6+2+2+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+5+5+5+5+6+6+6+6+7+7+7+7+8+8+8+8+14+14+14+14+14+21+21+21+21+21";

    $res = '';
    $str_arr = explode('+',$str);
    foreach($str_arr as $key=>$val){
        if($val!=2)  {
            $res.= $val.'+';
        }
    }
    echo rtrim($res,'+');
```

Comment: but you want this output.See your question

Comment: do you want to remove the whole 2 from the string whether it is 2,21,22 or only 2

Answer (score 0):

```
$cookie = "4+5+6+2+2+2+2+3+3+3+3+4+4+4+4+5+5+5+5+6+6+6+6+7+7+7+7+8+8+8+8+14+14+14+14+14+21+21+21+21+21";
$replaces = array("/\\+2\\b/","/^2\+/");
$cookie = preg_replace($replaces,"",$cookie);
echo $cookie;
```